# Are there any free refactoring tools for verilog?

Tags: gratis, ide

For many programming languages there exist free IDEs with refactoring support to allow one to break out chunks of code into new functions/classes with minimal risk of error.

I would like to do similar things to some of my Verilog HDL code breaking an over-sized module into smaller modules, but I don't do enough of this sort of work to justify buying a paid tool. Are there any free (free as in foss would be preferable, but free as in beer would be tolerable) tools that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

One approach that might be worth looking into is using Abstract Syntax Trees (ASTs):

```
Verilog -> AST -> [refactor AST] -> AST -> Verilog
```

There are a number of [python](https://www.python.org/) tools that can do the first & last steps one being [pyverilog](https://pypi.org/project/pyverilog/) *I recommend that you start by checking that you can do a round trip without any refactoring as the first step.*

There are also some python projects that can perform refactoring operations on and AST - [RedBaron](https://redbaron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) looks very interesting.

This might be a little more "roll your own" than you prefer but is:

- Free: FOSS
- Free: Gratis
- Cross Platform